# Access/SQL Union

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT Campaign, Prem1Item, Prem1Qty, Prem1Drop, Prem2Item, Prem2Qty, Prem2Drop, Prem3Item, Prem3Qty, Prem3Drop, Prem4Item, Prem4Qty,  Prem4Drop, Prem5Item, Prem5Qty, Prem5Drop, Prem10ItemPkging, AckLtr1TypeCode, AckLtr10ItemPkging, ContactID
    FROM [TU FAR Before VB]
UNION ALL 
SELECT Campaign, Prem6Item, Prem6Qty, Prem6Drop, Prem7Item, Prem7Qty, Prem7Drop, Prem8Item, Prem8Qty, Prem8Drop, Prem9Item, Prem9Qty, Prem9Drop, NULL, NULL, NULL, Prem10ItemPkging, NULL, AckLtr10ItemPkging, ContactID
FROM [TU FAR Before VB]
WHERE NOT
 (
    (Prem6Item IS NULL) AND (Prem7Item IS NULL) AND (Prem8Item IS NULL)
     AND (Prem9Item IS NULL)
 );
```

In the above code everything works great I just need to add a field to the table called `Continued` that equals `"Y"` for all of the records that have been created because it had more than the 5 items and `"N"` for all of the records that have the first 5 items.

I wanted to know if there is a way to do this without having to completely make a new table?

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

Chuck

Comment: it's a little unclear what you are asking.  what's the table structure for the `continued` table? Is a `union all` actually necessary here? it looks like your query can be accomplished in one SQL statement

Comment: I thought I could do it by appending it to another table and check for duplicate ContactID but my attempt at that failed. That is what I meant by making a new table.

Comment: I need the continued field for when I export to another program that can only recognize 5 products. If we have more than that it has a "continuation" field to let it know that the next 5 items are a continuation of the previous order.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want.  You probably either want a literal like `"Y" as Continued` or you want to add a conditional e.g. `IIF(SomeCondition, "Y", "N") as Continued` Can you add some sample data, expected output and some more clarity around why it should be "Y" or "N"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a hardcoded column in each of the queries:

```
SELECT  ....,
        'N' AS Continued
FROM    ...
UNION ALL
SELECT  ....,
        'Y' AS Continued
FROM    ...
```

So your full query would become:

```
SELECT  Campaign, 
        Prem1Item, 
        Prem1Qty, 
        Prem1Drop, 
        Prem2Item, 
        Prem2Qty, 
        Prem2Drop, 
        Prem3Item, 
        Prem3Qty, 
        Prem3Drop, 
        Prem4Item, 
        Prem4Qty,  
        Prem4Drop, 
        Prem5Item, 
        Prem5Qty, 
        Prem5Drop, 
        Prem10ItemPkging, 
        AckLtr1TypeCode, 
        AckLtr10ItemPkging, 
        ContactID,
        'N' [Continued]
FROM    [TU FAR Before VB]
UNION ALL 
SELECT   Campaign, 
        Prem6Item, 
        Prem6Qty, 
        Prem6Drop, 
        Prem7Item, 
        Prem7Qty, 
        Prem7Drop, 
        Prem8Item, 
        Prem8Qty, 
        Prem8Drop, 
        Prem9Item, 
        Prem9Qty, 
        Prem9Drop, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        Prem10ItemPkging, 
        NULL, 
        AckLtr10ItemPkging, 
        ContactID,
        'Y' [Continued]
FROM    [TU FAR Before VB]
WHERE   NOT
        (       Prem6Item IS NULL
            AND Prem7Item IS NULL
            AND Prem8Item IS NULL
            AND Prem9Item IS NULL
        );
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Didn't even think of that..... Feel pretty dumb right now. Again thanks!